# How to work with BucketedRandomProjectionLSH

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, lsh

I have two datasets dfA (5M) and dfB (6K).
I train the [LSH](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features#bucketed-random-projection-for-euclidean-distance) on spark 2.2:

```
val brp = new BucketedRandomProjectionLSH()
  .setBucketLength(2.0)
  .setNumHashTables(3)
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("hashes")

val brp_model = brp.fit(dfA)

val dfA_transformed = brp_model.transform(dfA)
val dfB_transformed = brp_model.transform(dfB)
```

I track a pair of records having distance of 17.59:

```
val uidB = 601295446577L

val key_s = dfB_transformed
    .filter(col("uid") === lit(uidB))
    .select("features")
    .as[String].collect()(0)

val key = Vectors.parse(key_s).asML

brp_model
.approxNearestNeighbors(dfA_transformed, key, 2, "distance")
.drop("features")
.show(5,false)

+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
|uid          |hashes                 |distance          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
|1194000912899|[[0.0], [-1.0], [-1.0]]|17.592033410506907|
|163208761881 |[[0.0], [-1.0], [-1.0]]|19.912395647390348|
+-------------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

So far, so good. But when I use approxSimilarityJoin I don't get my pair of 17.59 but rather others from A with much larger distances.

```
.approxSimilarityJoin(dfA_transformed, dfB_transformed, 25.0, "distance")
.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
.filter(col("datasetB.uid") === lit(uidB))
+-------------+------------+------------------+
|         uidA|        uidB|          distance|
+-------------+------------+------------------+
| 128849023798|601295446577|20.977834057053013|
|1005022360587|601295446577|21.919213729270727|
| 463856471960|601295446577|22.595725081515273|
| 670014905945|601295446577|23.396613579631136|
|1262720389581|601295446577| 24.03850371925476|
|1073741843710|601295446577|24.095447353196946|
+-------------+------------+------------------+
```

More precisely, if I use *persist* I never get that pair, while as without *persist* I always see it present.

Each run the resulting dataset shows heavy fluctuations in size:

```
brp_model
.approxSimilarityJoin(dfA_transformed, dfB_transformed, 25.0, "distance")
.persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)
.count() 
// 20741736,18820380,20772153


brp_model
.approxSimilarityJoin(dfA_transformed, dfB_transformed, 25.0, "distance")
.count() 
// 19371911,17323851,20074502
```

I understand the random nature of hash collisions, nevertheless:

1. Any wrong using *persist* here?
2. What might be done to improve the accuracy of *approxSimilarityJoin*? I see no tools to evaluate how good the BucketLength is.
3. If I know A and B ahead should I train *brp* on union of A and B?
4. Is it a more stable way to iterate over B and query each record by key?